# How to use phototransistor in Multisim?

Tags: multisim

I've multisim 14.2.
I not succeeded in make a phototransistor or photodiode to work.

I've tried a circuit like this
[image]

But no way to work.

Any clues? I don't know how to do it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372062L-01/multisim/ratedphototransistor/)?

Comment: why do you believe that the LED shines on the phototransistor?

Comment: The problem was the limitations of my multisim version. I've tried another version and I got it working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use an LED, you need to use a PhotoDiode instead.

If you download and search the Multisim Component Guide for Photo, you'll find the following explanation for both the Rated Photo-Diode and Rated Photo-Transistor:

> The photodiode emits a source of infrared light which is detected by the phototransistor.
> These devices are intended to be used in pairs.
> You must specify a light channel in each of these paired parts (photodiode and
> phototransistor). This is done in the Value tab of the component’s properties screen. Each
> diode must have a different value for its light channel, however, the phototransistor can share
> the same value with several other phototransistors.

Answer (score -1):

'Green' components have no model, so they will never work
https://kazus.ru/forums/images/smilies/icon_laugh.gif